# WordPress Layer Slider - Weird behavior, possible jQuery Conflict?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, conflict

I just purchased the LayerSlider for WordPress plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246) and tried to embed it in my theme using the do_shortcode method and a call to the slider I created.

I am experiencing what I believe to be a conflict between scripts from my theme and the plugin.
The slider shows up, but in an absolute position way outside its containing div. It doesnt animate at all, and shows all layers statically.

I get this error in the console: `lsShowNotice is not defined`

If I enable the slider's global setting for 'Put JS includes to body', the slider then shows up in the correct spot, but does weird animations and moves the layers outside the container div and doesn't hide them. Then they all just disappear and it doesn't cycle as it should.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You know this will be very difficult to answer without knowing which plugins you have installed and how they all play together... and with an actual link to the error it will not be good since it may be dead within a couple of days or hrs. The best advice in this situation is to run off all your plugins except this slider and turn on one by one to see with what plugin you hare having issues, then view the source to make sure jquery is only loaded once, so on. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am experiencing (but different) errors. The slider works okay when I am working on it. But when I want to work the next day, it appears broke. Maybe only the first slide animates then it apparently goes in a loop (the revolving icon keeps rotating). This happened thrice, in different subdomains and fresh installs and no other plugin.

I used ProConsultant from  Premopress and Genesis+Executive themes and same result. the layerslider plugin is latest version 4.6.0 and I used the HomeSlider widget for both, wordpress 3.6

How to troubleshoot?